# How to show video from post on the all posts page?

Tags: posts, videos

So I have a theme in development. When I go to make a post, the post formats don't seem to change anything. I'm not sure if they're supposed to change the page or not...

But what I want is for when I do a video post (either an uploaded video or a link), for the video to show up on the Posts page (which displays all posts).

I've tried adding a couple of things to functions.php, but to no avail... Can anyone help please? Images show up, just not videos

Answer (score 0):

For a post format, you can refer to this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats

To show videos on posts page,just modify the excerpt filter and display the excerpt.

**Add following code in `functions.php`**

```
function custom_wp_trim_excerpt($text) {
    $raw_excerpt = $text;
    if ( '' == $text ) {
        $text = get_the_content(''); // Original Content
        $text = strip_shortcodes($text); // Minus Shortcodes
        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text); // Filters
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text); // Replace
        $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 50); // Length
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '<a class="readmore" href="'. get_permalink() .'">&raquo;</a>');
        $text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
        // Use First Video as Excerpt
        $postcustom = get_post_custom_keys();
        global $post; 
        $postid = $post->ID;
        if ($postcustom){
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($postcustom as $key){
            if (strpos($key,'oembed')){
                foreach (get_post_custom_values($key) as $video){
                    if ($i == 1){
                        $text = $video."<br/>".$text;
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

**Put the excerpt tag where you want to display the video.**

```
echo get_the_excerpt();
```

**Add video URL in post content (visual editor) and it will display video in excerpt also.**

like : https://vimeo.com/VIMEO_ID